# Accessing HashMap through a singleton

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap

I have a Record class which extends a DoctorRecord class. I want threads to store these records in a hash map which I create as a singleton. My problem is every time a thread adds a record to the hash map and I try to print it's size in the main method (once all the threads have finished executing), I always get a size of 0, as if no modifications were made. However, when I print the size of the map within the method adding the records, it shows the correct size. I'm assuming it's an issue with a pass-by-value mechanic but I can't seem to correct the problem.

**Hash Map singleton class:**

```
public class MtlHashMap {

    private static HashMap<Character, ArrayList<Record>> hmMtl = new HashMap<Character, ArrayList<Record>>();

    public static HashMap<Character, ArrayList<Record>> getInstance(){
        return hmMtl;
    }

}
```

**Thread method being called inside the overridden run() method** (The hash map contains one list for every letter of the alphabet)

```
public synchronized void createDRecord(String firstName, String lastName, String address, long phone, String specialization, String location){

    System.out.println("Create D Record");
    DoctorRecord d1 = new DoctorRecord(firstName, lastName, address, phone, specialization, location);

        hm = MtlHashMap.getInstance();

    Character ch = lastName.toLowerCase().charAt(0);

    ArrayList<Record> list = (ArrayList<Record>) hm.get(ch);

    if(list == null){
        System.out.println("Create list");
        list = new ArrayList<Record>();
    }

    list.add(d1);
    System.out.println("Size of list " + ch + " is " + list.size());

    hm.put(ch,list);
    System.out.println("Size of " + location + "hash map is " + hm.size());
}
```

**Main**

```
public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

    System.out.println("Main");

    ManagerClient m1 = new ManagerClient("mtl");
    ManagerClient m2 = new ManagerClient("mtl");
    ManagerClient m3 = new ManagerClient("mtl");
    ManagerClient m4 = new ManagerClient("mtl");


    //Create Doctor Record
    m1.run("Joana", "Sam", "272 Montpellier", 1231, "surgeon", "mtl");
    m2.run("Joana", "Sam", "34 Lake", 1231, "surgeon", "mtl");
    m4.run("Joana", "Sam", "34 Lake", 1231, "surgeon", "mtl");

    m1.join();
    m2.join();
    m4.join();

    System.out.println("Size of MTL hash map is: " + MtlHashMap.getInstance().size());
    System.out.println("Size of LVL hash map is: " + LvlHashMap.getInstance().size());
    System.out.println("Size of DDO hash map is: " + DdoHashMap.getInstance().size());
```

**Manager Client Class**

```
public class ManagerClient extends Thread{ 
private String location;
private String id;
private static int managerIdCounter = 1000; //Maintains unique global IDs


public ManagerClient(String location){
    this.location = location.toLowerCase();
    this.id = location.toLowerCase()+managerIdCounter++;

}

public String getLocation(){
    return (this.location).toLowerCase();
}

public String getmId(){
    return this.id;
}

//Different run method overloads for each of the four methods needed,
//with the appropriate server being called using the locateServer() method


//Default run method never used, but must be overridden anyway
public void run(){
    System.out.println("This should never appear");
}

//Create Doctor Record (5 String and 1 long argument) SYNCHRONIZE THIS FOR SAFE RUNNING
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public synchronized void run(String firstName, String lastName, String address, long phone, String specialization, String location){

    System.out.println("Manager " + this.getmId() + " creates a D record");

    try{
        System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        String path = "rmi://localhost:2020/"+getLocation();
        ClinicServerInterface server = (ClinicServerInterface)Naming.lookup(path);

        server.createDRecord(firstName, lastName, address, phone, specialization, location);
    }catch(Exception e){
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

//Create Nurse Record (6 String arguments)
public synchronized void run(String firstName, String lastName, String designation, String status, String statusDate){
    System.out.println("Manager " + this.getmId() + " creates a N record");

    try{
        System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        String path = "rmi://localhost:2020/"+getLocation();
        ClinicServerInterface server = (ClinicServerInterface)Naming.lookup(path);
        server.createNRecord(firstName, lastName, designation, status, statusDate, getLocation());
    }catch(Exception e){
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}

//Get Record Counts (1 int argument)
public void run(int type){
    String location = this.location;

}

//Edit Record (3 String arguments)
public void run(String recrodID, String fieldName, String newValue){
    String location = this.location;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you use a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) instead?

Comment: Show us the whole code. Where do you call the createDRecord method? also you dont have any threads here, all the code runs synchronously because you call run instead of start. So join doesnt do anything either.

Comment: I've added the Manager Client Class, I call the run method because I need the thread to choose between 4 different methods to run, so I overrode the run method with 4 different signatures. I don't know if that's bad practice or not, but I did not know how else to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's up with your hash map, but your program does not create any threads.  Your main() routine does this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ...
    ManagerClient m1 = new ManagerClient("mtl");
    ...
    m1.run("Joana", "Sam", "272 Montpellier", 1231, "surgeon", "mtl");
    ...
    m1.join();
    ...
}
```

That does not create a thread.  That creates a `ManagerClient` object, and a `ManagerClient` object is a kind of `Thread` object; but a `Thread` is not a *thread*.

A *thread* is an operating system object that executes your code, and a `Thread` object is a Java object that your program uses to create an manage the life cycle of a *thread*.  The *thread* will not be created until your program calls `m1.start()`.

---

If you change your program to call `m1.start()`, here is what will happen:  Your program will print `This should never appear`.

That's because your `ManagerClient` class overrides `Thread.run()` as follows:

```
//Default run method never used, but must be overridden anyway
public void run(){
    System.out.println("This should never appear");
}
```

Your `ManagerClient` class also defines some other methods named "run".  E.g.:

```
public synchronized void run(String firstName, String lastName, String address, long phone, String specialization, String location)
```

But that is a *different* method.  If your program calls `m1.start()` to start the new thread, the new thread will call `m1.run()` and *NOT* `m1.run("Joana", "Sam", "272 Montpellier", ...)`.

There's nothing you can do to change that.  It's just how `Thread.start()` works.

The normal way to pass arguments to a thread that you explicitly create and start like that is to pass them through the constructor.  E.g.;

```
ManagerClient m1 = new ManagerClient("Joana", "Sam", "272 Montpillier", ...);
m1.start();
```

---

But you might want to reconsider creating and starting threads in that way.

Your `run(...)` methods each just do one thing and then return.  A thread *dies* when it's `run()` method returns.  Creating and killing threads to perform simple tasks is a Bad Idea.  Not that it will cause any harm in a toy program like your assignment, but in real-world software, the good idea that you should be using instead is called a *thread pool.*

You can learn about thread pools by reading up on `ExecutorService`, and `ThreadPoolExecutor`, and `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`.  And, by checking out the Java Concurrency Tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Comment: Thanks for the help @jameslarge, I modified my code based on your suggestion and the multithreading runs correctly now. Now to figure out what's going on with the hash map!

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the [Javadoc of `HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized**. If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it *must* be synchronized externally.

*But, he protests, the method* is *`synchronized`*. Well, yes, it is, but not in a useful way.

If `public synchronized void createDRecord(...)` is a method inside the `ManagerClient` class, then the monitor on which you are synchronizing is the `ManagerClient` instance - and you have 4 of those. So whilst monitors are being acquired and released, nothing else is contending them, so it is like the synchronization is not there.

You should either use a `synchronized` block inside the method to lock on the hash map itself:

```
public void createDRecord(...) {
    HashMap<Character, ArrayList<Record>> hm = MtlHashMap.getInstance();
    synchronized (hm) {
      // Mutually exclusive access to hm goes here.
    }
}
```

or use a `ConcurrentHashMap`, like @MickMnemonic suggested in his comment.

---

You should also make the static hash map `final`, in order to guarantee that its initialized value is visible in all threads:

```
private static final HashMap<Character, ArrayList<Record>> hmMtl = new HashMap<>();
               ^
```

Comment: @T.Claverie The problem with `Hashtable` is that whilst the individual accesses are synchronized, the sequence of actions performed in OP's code would be done in separate calls to the `Hashtable`, and thus would not be atomic. For instance, two threads could happen to call `hm.get(ch)` sequentially, and both get `null`, because the first hasn't yet called `put`; thus, both would insert a new list (sequentially); but the second one would stomp the first. Wrapping the whole get/create if null/put in a synchronized block avoids this; (cont.)

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` provides a `putIfAbsent` method (and `computeIfAbsent`, in Java 8+), which allows this to be done atomically too, without locking. In short, `Hashtable` without *more* synchronization doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Due to the assignment constraints, I am obliged to use HashMap. I know my synchronization is not well done for now, I am simply trying to modify the hash map properly. I am still getting a size of 0 at the end of my main. Anyone know why?